# how does reference object work in java

Tags: java, object

can any one makes me understand? how does reference object work in java from below code i have object `r1` and reference object `r2`, 
`Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(); Rectangle r2 = r1;`
when i print both `r1` and `r2` the output is some thing like this `Rectangle@17f7bec4`(output same for both). ok i understand this is memory address right? if i print below code

```
  r1.length = 50;
  r2.length = 20;

  System.out.println("Value of R1's Length : " + r1.length);
  System.out.println("Value of R2's Length : " + r2.length);
```

the output of above code is :

**Value of R1's Length : 20**

**Value of R2's Length : 20**

i can not understand this output why both have `20` value ?
if this is because of referencing memory then when i use below code

```
  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
  Rectangle r2 = r1;
  r2 = null;

 System.out.println("R1 : " + r1);
 System.out.println("R2 : " + r2);
```

the output of both objects:

**R1 : `Rectangle@17f7bec4`**

**R2 : null**

why r1 does not have `null` value ? this is the **point** which is confusing me
below is running code..

```
class Rectangle {
  double length;
  double breadth;
}

class RectangleDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
  Rectangle r2 = r1;

r1.length = 50;
r2.length = 20;


  System.out.println("R1 : " + r1);
  System.out.println("Value of R1's Length : " + r1.length);
  System.out.println("Value of R2's Length : " + r2.length);
r2 = null;
  System.out.println("R2 : " + r2);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is created in heap and  it has an address.

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
// r1 is pointing to that address
Rectangle r2 = r1;
// now r2 is pointing to the same address (same object) with r1
r2 = null;
// now r2 is null, but the object is still in the heap.
// r2 doesn't point to that object anymore.
```

[image]

Comment: `// now r2 is null, but the object is still in the heap.` ok! but when 
i assigned 20 to r2 (r2.length = 20; ) then why both have same values ? object is still in the heap

Comment: You assigned r2 to null after setting object's length to 20

Answer (score 2):

`r1` and `r2` are **references** to objects. In first case they both point to the same object, in second case `r2` points to `null`. In your code there is **only one** not-null object and **two references**.

---

Comments to your code

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();    //object creation, make r1 point to created object
Rectangle r2 = r1;                 //r2 now points to the same object, that was created a line above

r1.length = 50;    //change lenght of object r1 points to
r2.length = 20;    //change lenght of object r2 points to (the same object as r1 points to)

r2 = null; //make r2 point to null
```

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way for any language.

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(); //r1 refers to this new Rectangle
Rectangle r2 = r1; //now r2 refers to the same Rectangle r1 refers to
r2 = null; //now is referring to null
```

You could set r1 to null and it will have the same behavior.

If you change r2 to final it will not allow it to be changed.

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
final Rectangle r2 = r1; //now r2 will be forever referring to the Rectangle above even if you change r1 to null
```

check it out if you change r1 to null r2 will still point to the Rectangle... when you tell r2=r1... r2 is NOT pointing to r1, r2 is actually pointing to the Rectangle itself!

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(2, 2);
final Rectangle r2 = r1; // now r2 will be forever referring to the
             // Rectangle above even if you change r1 to
             // null
r1 = null;
System.out.print(r2.getWidth());
```

output width is still 2 and no null error.